# Where do I place my css files in Laravel?

Tags: css, laravel

I understand I can make changes to resources/assets/sass/app.scss in my Laravel projects and the changes will be reflected after running npm run dev or npm run watch.

But what do I do when I have a dozen .css files?  Where do I place them and how do I compile them?

I have looked through the documentation and quite a few Laracasts videos and have not found an answer.

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix) states

> Again, like the less method, you may compile multiple Sass files into >their own respective CSS files and even customize the output directory >of the resulting CSS:
>
> mix.sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css')
>     .sass('resources/sass/admin.sass', 'public/css/admin');

So does this mean if I have an admin.css file I would rename it to admin.scss and place it in the sass directory?  Then behind the scenes Laravel would compile that and place it in public/css/admin? So each .css file needs to become an .scss file and I have to list each one in webpack.mix.js?

This may be really simple but I've spent many hours trying to understand.

Comment: That's right. Convert them to `.scss` files. You can also keep one main `app.scss` that will import all the other `.scss` files. By the way, you *could* just import the css files as they are, but that wouldn't be really a good idea if you plan on working with those files later on. It would be best to have a good `.scss` workflow in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the CSS files where ever you want. But the best practice is create a css/ folder in public directory and put all your css files in that folder. then use  tag to include css files.

If you have multiple files like admin.css , user.css etc. you can simply create a styles.css file and use @import statement to include all other css files in one file. Then it is enough to link only the styles.css file to any blade file you like.

I hope this may help you.

For any doubts leave comment.